# URI of same element in two documents - stylesheet

Tags: xslt

I have two xml config files that has same elements. I want to compare if the uri is same for them. If they are different I need to print the element name.

Doc1 :

```
   <config>
       <google>
         <url>google.com/api/getcoordinates</url>
       </google>
       <ranst>
        <url>http://ranst.com/getranst</url>
       <ranst>
     </config>
```

doc2:

```
  <config>
    <google>
       <url>google.com/api/getlocationcordinates</url>
    </google>
    <akamai>
       <url>http://akamai.com/redirectlocation/eastregion</url>
    <akamai>
  </config>
```

Document1 and document2 has google in common , but the uri's are different. So I want to call this out. How can I do this using XSLT ?
Thanks.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: also are you using xslt 1.0 or 2.0